# Invalid link file

Tags: image, magento, caching, console, element

When browsing most pages (the home page specifically), the site is generating an invalid link to an image file:

Comment: Can anyone help me with this issue? I know it's pretty vague but still looking for some help if possible.

Comment: Which site? What technology the site is in? How are you inserting images? Your question doesn't list anything useful for someone to be able to help you out

Comment: That's what i figured it might be, how do i fix this issue? @TarunLalwani

Comment: Post your apache config

Comment: httpd.conf file or htaccess? @TarunLalwani edited above with httpd.conf file.

Comment: @TarunLalwani, please let me know if you'd like me to post my htaccess as well.

Comment: Please post htaccess also and if you have any conf related to the site in `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/`, post that too. `httpd.conf` is generic and won't help much here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159921/discussion-between-singleton-and-tarun-lalwani).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed over chat, your Apache config has

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

What that does is that if a file doesn't exists, it is tried with a `/` appended at the end. That would mean that the png file you have actually doesn't exists and should give you 404, but this rules give you 301 with `/` appended and that then comes out as 404.

So the problem is simply the image is actually missing

Comment: Thanks again Tarun!